Question about selection sort comparisons
I am looking into this challenge:

Consider an array that contains two successive copies of the integers 1 through n, in ascending
order. For example, here is the array when n = 8: 1234567812345678
Note that the length of the array is 2n, not n.
(a) How many compares does selection sort make to sort the array as a function of n?
Use tilde notation to simplify your answer.

I thought it's going to be 4N*N comparisons, but the answer is n*n, can someone explain plz

Please provide the source for the claim it should be n*n.

Why did you think it's 4N*N? What even is N?

What's your selection sort code?

You wrote:

I thought it's going to be 4N*N comparisons, but the answer is n*n

Both statements are wrong.
Note that the number of comparisons in (standard) selection sort does not depend on the contents of the input array, so whether it is 1234567812345678 or 4836142281637557 doesn't matter. Wikipedia explains:

Selecting the minimum requires scanning  elements (taking −1 comparisons) and then swapping it into the first position. Finding the next lowest element requires scanning the remaining −1 elements (taking −2 comparisons) and so on. Therefore, the total number of comparisons is
      (−1) + (−2) + ... + 1

This is (²−)/2, but as in your input the length is 2 instead of , we need to introduce that factor of 2:
      ((2)²−2)/2 = 2²−
Here is an illustration of that formula in the form of a runnable JavaScript snippet, that executes selection sort on your example input. It counts the number of comparisons made and outputs both that count and the result of the above formula:


function selectionSort(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        let choice = i;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            ++count;
            if (arr[j] < arr[choice]) choice = j;
        }
        [arr[i], arr[choice]] = [arr[choice],arr[i]];
    }
    return count;
}

// Test:
let n = 8;
let arr = Array.from({length: 2*n}, (_, i) => i % n + 1);
console.log("Input:      ", ...arr);
let count = selectionSort(arr);
console.log("Sorted:     ", ...arr);
console.log("Comparisons:", count);
console.log("Formula:    ", 2*n*n - n);



So the number of comparisons is 2²−. Now if we wanted an approximation (using tilde), we could write this as ~2², which for the example would be ~128, which is close to the actual 120 comparisons, but ~² seems wrong, as 64 is quite far from 120.
NB: this is O(²) if we use big O notation, but that is not an approximation, but an indication of asymptotic growth.

but does that mean if the complexity of selection sort if I insert n input numbers, if there is an intermediate array that doubles it, putting elements first in ascending  order followed by same numbers in descending order, my input will still be n, doesn't that mean my comparisons now compared to input  comparisons is 2n2n so it should be 4nn

Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The content of the array does not matter, only its size.

Can you clarify? What does "my comparisons now compared to input comparisons" mean? What is "input comparisons"? Did you count the number of comparisons with a real execution of selection sort? For any values you store in an array of size 2, the number of comparisons will always be 2²-.Just count it. Or are you confusing with some other sorting algorithm, not selection sort?

"~4n²" could be explained by also counting the j < arr.length comparisons. And maybe n² is possible with some optimized implementation, but they'd need to show that implementation.
